# Data and Files Migration from Microsoft SharePoint to a AWS S3 and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, sharepoint, architecture, data-migration

I have a MERN Stack application, that has a document management with a version control system implemented.

I want to add **import from SharePoint** feature to this system as most of our clients will need it. I want to do the following:

- Add an import button.
- The button will trigger a backend that will somehow pull the metadata and files from Microsoft SharePoint and it will transform the data to our data structure so that it can have a proper folder and files format saved in our DB.
- Finally I want to upload these actual files to AWS S3 from SharePoint (Maybe a long running background job or queue is useful here).

Can anyone suggest a best possible way to set this up from an architecture perspective? Or technical sides that I may need to consider to make this happen or what's the best possible way to perform this ?

Any suggestion about resources' and technologies will also help.